# EditText listener not running

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm creating an EditText listener by inflating an EditText view from another layout. The listener doesn't work. I'm trying to place print statements below but none of them are called after the `digitText.addTextChangedListener(...)`. Anything before it is called. I made sure the id's were correct and it wasn't getting an null pointers inflating the views. Any suggestions on why it's not working?

```
public void digitsListener () {

            LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
            View dialpadLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialpad, null);
            EditText digitText = (EditText)dialpadLayout.findViewById(R.id.digits);
            digitText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    System.out.println("If this prints it works.");
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            });
}
```

Here's the EditText view inside the dialpad.xml

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/digits"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>
```

Comment: there is no System.out.print() in android. Use log instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `EditText` has to be visible at screen in order you can interact with, so probably you do not need the `inflater`. The `inflater` returns a new object every time it inflates a view. So the  `EditText` you are interacting with is different from the one the inflater has returned. If you are inside an Activity, you can change your code this way.

```
public void digitsListener () {


            EditText digitText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.digits);
            digitText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    System.out.println("If this prints it works.");
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Removing the inflator crashes the program on `digitText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()..` with a NPE

Comment: think about it. If findViewById returns null means that your EditText is not visible, am I wrong?

Comment: Here's my situation: This activity is calling 4 other fragments as tabs. I'm running this listener in the main activity, not one of the fragments. Should I place it in the appropriate fragment?

Comment: you have to run the snippet in the place where the view belongs. otherwise it does make no sense

Comment: Yea i just placed it in the fragment and it works. I was hoping inflating it in the outer activity would also work. I guess you have to have it directly in the fragment

Comment: No. As I have already told you, inflater returns every time a new object

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on Android? Then there is no `System.out.print()`

You need to use the LogCat instead:

`Log.i("tag", "If this prints it works");`
Just choose any tag you want, it really doesnt matter, you just need it for finding it by using tag: (eg tag:error) in the searchbox above logcat

"Log.i" is for information, "Log.w" for warnings, "Log.e" for error-messages

If you want the message to be displayed on your phone, you could use Toasts instead:

`Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "If this prints it works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

toast.show();`
(See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html))

Comment: No, the phone is plugged in and I'm looking at the statments on LogCat in Eclipse

Comment: Doesnt change anything, there is no `System.out.print`

Comment: The toasts aren't appearing either